# How to use boost mpi broadcast function in an efficient way?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, boost-mpi

I am trying to broadcast a value from a root process and receive it in all other processes. I have implemented it in the following two formats.
1. I used broadcast function in all processes (root and all other slaves)

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
  mpi::communicator world;

  std::string value;
  if (world.rank() == 0) {
    value = "Hello, World!";
  }
  broadcast(world, value, 0);

  std::cout << "Process #" << world.rank() << " says " << value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

2. I call broadcast only from root while call receive from other processes as follows:

```
  if (world.rank() == 0) {
    value = "Hello, World!";
    broadcast(world, value, 0);
  }
  else {
    world.recv(boost::mpi::any_source, boost::mpi::any_tag, value);
  }
```

both seem to work similar in these examples, but I want to know if there is any preferences in terms of code efficiency and performance here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the plain `broadcast`.

The second version is not a correct MPI program. If it works, it is only by chance. In general `broadcast` and the other collectives are highly optimized and can utilize system topology information. Thus they perform better than if you would implement it on your own using point-to-point messages. Also they express your communication structure in a more abstract way, resulting in cleaner code.